# No folders or links on desktop in Communitheme

Tags: gnome, nautilus, .desktop

I've installed communtiheme on my Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME Shell v3.28.1.

I cannot enter folders (file opening does work) and the default icons only appear on the desktop but don't exist inside.

Even if I create a folder and it appears on the terminal I cannot enter her via Nautilus (GNOME explorer).

What is the problem here ?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As shown by `ls ~/Desktop` there is no folder on the Desktop. First, try to create one and then to double-click on it. `mkdir '~/Desktop/A Folder'`

Comment: @cmak.fr I've already tried that. It shows the directory but you cannot open it using Nautilus GNOME

Comment: it should be related to Nautilus more than Communitheme. Could you reproduce the same issue with Adwaita or another theme?

Comment: @Roey: Please edit your post and copy/paste the output of this command : `xdg-user-dir DESKTOP; ls -lah $(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)`

Comment: @clobrano I tried various configurations of themes and icons and it still doesn't work. I even tried to login as (the cog in the lockscreen) default Ububntu and not Ubuntu Commuitheme. The problem did start with communitheme and I already posted an issue on their project in Github.

Comment: @Roey are you able to downgrade Nautilus instead? If this works, it would be clear that Nautilus is the "problem"

Comment: @clobrano How do I downgrade nautilus (and after that return to the updated version) ? To what version ? (My current version is 3.26.3)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-communitheme/issues/217#issuecomment-398326746) is the answer I got from a communitheme issue I've opened in Github.

[GNOME 3.28 Removes Option to Put Icons on the Desktop](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/gnome-desktop-icons-removed-3-28)

It's a pity. Currently there is no working GNOME shell extension to workaround that.

Currently I'm sticking with GNOME (Ubuntu) for compatibility reasons though KDE's new plasma (Kubntu) GUI is much more intuitive and with greater functionality

I was very impressed with it's KDE's Dolphin among other things.
I'll try Nemo, I hope it will have most it's features.